# Do values with same hash go in same bucket of std::unordered_map?

Tags: c++, stl, c++11

If two keys for a std::unordered_map have the same hash value, is it guaranteed by the standard that they will go into the same bucket? We are assuming that the keys are not equal according to the template equality predicate, they only have the same hash value.

Bonus question: If same hash does not imply same bucket, then what is the purpose of being able to traverse buckets individually?

Comment: Well, from the "bonus" question, you can find the answer to the actual question.

Comment: For the bonus question, knowing the bucket would be useful only with a stipulation that a certain method of *probing* ([linear](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_probing), [quadratic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_probing), etc.) is implemented. Having to publish this would put undue constraints on the implementation, though.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight, the implementation is constrained to use a bucketed hash, rather than an open addressing scheme. IIRC, this question was discussed at length by the committee. Also, I added a bonus answer to the bonus question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Objects with the same hash are put into the same bucket by unordered associative containers. Consequently, two equal objects must have the same hash.

23.2.5 paragraph 8:

> The elements of an unordered associative container are organized into buckets. Keys with the same hash code appear in the same bucket.

Bonus question: Why might you want to traverse buckets individually?

Bonus answer: Because you want to process the container's contents in parallel. The bucket iterators are independent of each other, so each thread can process a bucket without co-ordination (provided no new entries are added to the container). And the buckets should be roughly the same size, so they provide a convenient parallelisation quantum.

Comment: That's not really accurate, or true. For starters, objects that compare unequal are *distinct* even if they have the same hash. That's the whole point of hash collision management.

Comment: @KerrekSB, true, I was imprecise. I should have said "treated identically for bucketing". I edited the answer.

Comment: Oh, how interesting, I never knew that that was specified. I'll delete my answer.

Comment: I would love to know the discussions that led to this outcome. The standard isn't usually this restrictive.

Comment: @MarkRansom, I have no insight into the standards committee meeting process, but Matt Austern's proposal went through a number of revisions; Google found me the 2003 version at http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2003/n1456.html . This includes Austern's explanation for the choice of chained hashing, and also a brief rationale for the bucket interface (debugging; could be more efficient).